# what is wrong with the current way of developing/packaing/distributing a (large) java (web) application?

Tags: java, web-applications, architecture, jar, osgi

There are lots of applications are moving towards osgi. And there are lots of material on the internet talk about benefits of using OSGi. But I fail to see the problems the current way of building/distributing a large java web application using non-OSGi(old way).  Could someone

- first outline the non-OSGi and OSGi way of developing,packing,distributing a large java web application.
- Secondly point out the the problem associated with non-OSGi way?
- Thirdly, how moving to OSGi would solve these problems. Maybe also give concrete examples  and reference resources.

Comment: +1 good question. I also feel like OSGi is a solution waiting for a problem (in the context of big JEE apps, at least)

Comment: @JB Nizet - OSGi has been serving the embedded market for +10 years, the Eclipse project has never been better since migrating to OSGi.  Frankly JEE has had numerous, radically different, revisions and is still overly complex and inconsistent.  If it were a "solution waiting for a problem" then answer why are ALL THE APP SERVERS RUNNING ON OSGi?

Comment: I said *"in the context of big JEE apps, at least"*. Eclipse is based on installable and removable plugins, where OSGi is useful. App servers need some modularity in order to please the different customer profiles. My typical JEE app must pass a whole lot of acceptance tests each time the tiniest modification is done, and it's already hard enough to deploy with just one deliverable. Making it modular, IMHO just adds complexity, and doesn't fit the enterprise way of deploying apps. But that's just my feeling. YMMV.

Comment: @Michael Z: what is wrong is the "dependency hell" or *"jar hell"* if you want.  Large JEE apps very often use (and are stuck on) old outdated *jar* and cannot replace them with newer versions because they cannot afford to "jump" from, say, 1.2 to 2.0.  So they're stuck with a dependency on *Buzzwordenterprisey 1.2* and shall never update to (backward-incompatible) 2.0.  This is *"jar hell"*.  OSGi fixes *jar hell*, amongst other.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I still respectfully disagree - the monolithic nature of your typical JEE app requires you run the full suite of tests for the tiniest change.  A modular app has well defined boundaries, so I only need to test those and deploy the actual fix - with zero downtime.  I've never met anyone who hot-redeploys their JEE apps, which is what app servers are supposed to be for =)  Additionally I fail to see such distinction between OSGi being useful for the app server but not for the app - if it's good for the goose, surely it's good for the gander?

Comment: The better a question, the faster it gets closed? Vote for reopen.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: If you have a piece of software that requires a certain version of a jar file, you cannot just replace it with a different version without making changes to the code base. OSGi does not magically change that. If you really want to go ahead and update dependency jar files without the vendor's cooperation, you can do that with a WAR file as well.

Comment: @Thilo: Then one should notify http://www.osgi.org/About/WhyOSGi because they specifically state the following *"OSGi technology solves JAR hell.... In standard Java, you're out of luck. In the OSGi environment, all bundles are carefully versioned and only bundles that can collaborate are wired together in the same class space."*  The way I read it, the OSGi "class space" help deal with that issue: updating *part* of their codebase to use a version of a *.jar* more recent than what the rest of the app is using.  This helps not having gigantic apps stuck on old *.jar*.

Answer (score 3):

The "current" way is WAR files, which are share-nothing. If you have three web applications and they all use commons-lang, you have to deploy three copies of the same jar file
(you might be right in that this is not a real problem for most people).

In addition to that, OSGi deploys bundles, not applications. This allows individual pieces of the application to be upgraded or activated at run-time. Not sure if that is important for many people, though. In fact, the missing "application granularity" leads to a great number of "movable parts" being visible in the form of all the bundles that make up an application. That confuses deployment people. OSGi is working on fixing that.

Finally, in OSGi the "container" functionality is also often part of the "application's" set of bundles (as opposed to a black box like JBoss that is clearly separate from application code). Bring your own container in a way. Very flexible, but again confusing for deployment people.